# Which makes an electromagnet stronger? AC or DC?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism

I need a clear answer and a good explanation about this. Please tell me what happens with an AC or DC current. I have already read a lot of books but I did not get this at all.

So please tell me: what makes an electromagnet stronger, AC or DC?

Comment: Don't shout please

Comment: Please note that Physics.StackExchange is not a homework help site. Please read [this Meta post on asking homework-like questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093).

Comment: @UnicornsAreVeryVeryYummy - I took the liberty of uncapping the question...

Comment: thats exactly what i wanted to ask

Comment: guys i am sorry but this is my first time on this site

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you drive an electromagnet with AC, part of the power will be dissipated in the form of eddy currents - both in the core of the magnet, and in the object you are trying to attract. These eddy currents dissipate power and generate magnetic fields that resist the flux change.

If you use DC, there are no eddy currents and all the power is available to generate / maintain the magnetic flux.

On the other hand, when you use AC there is a *peak* magnetic force that is greater than for a DC current with the same mean power, because the current is increasing to $\sqrt{2}$ of the mean value. This means that there will be times when the AC magnet is stronger. This can be important when you are trying to pull something towards your magnet (rather than just "holding" it) because the force of an electromagnet falls off *very* rapidly with distance. As long as the peak force is strong enough to start the object moving towards the magnet, it may be that the AC magnet "wins".

So

> For the same average power, a DC magnet can "hold" a greater force, but there are instances where an AC magnet can attract an object from a greater distance.

In other words - it depends what you mean by "stronger".

Comment: I MEANT AN INCREASE IN MAGNETIC FIELD  BY THE WORD STRONGER

Comment: Please stop using all caps. You need to define how you compare your AC and DC if you want to get a sensible answer. There are times during the AC cycle when there is no current, and the electromagnet has zero force.

Comment: all right i stopped using all caps